# Getting all buttons in a placeholder to have the same click event trigger

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, vb.net

I have a placeholder

```
<div class="main2" id="divAgentMenu" runat="server">
    <ul class="nav sf-menu">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phAgentMenu" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

And it is loaded with link buttons in code behind.  Unfortuantly, at this time I do not have access to the code that generates the buttons, so adding things(like ID) to the buttons is not doable.(if it is the only solution, time for me to see if I can get that changed, however)
Just to make things more interesting, I need to know which button was triggered, so I can generate the proper link.(Yes, I can generate the links as is, but it is an expensive operation, so I would rather do it only at need)
I was hoping that there would be a way to apply the onclick to the placeholder, or with a form, but I could get neither method to work

The Generated code, from run-time.

```
<ul class="nav sf-menu">

    <li class="home-li"><a class="home-link" onclick="popup(&#39;popUpDiv&#39;)" href="http://..."><img class="home-icon" src="Images/home_icon.png" alt="home" />Home&nbsp;&nbsp;</a><ul><li><a onclick="popup(&#39;popUpDiv&#39;)" href="http://...">Activity</a></li><li><a onclick="popup(&#39;popUpDiv&#39;)" href="http://...">My Profile</a></li></ul></li><li><a onclick="popup(&#39;popUpDiv&#39;)" href="http://...">Submission&nbsp;&nbsp;</a><ul><li><a onclick="popup(&#39;popUpDiv&#39;)" href="http://...">New Submission</a></li><li><a onclick="popup(&#39;popUpDiv&#39;)" href="http://...">Manage Submission</a></li><li><a onclick="popup(&#39;popUpDiv&#39;)" href="http://...">Bind Eligible Quotes</a></li></ul></li><li><a onclick="popup(&#39;popUpDiv&#39;)" href="http://...">Search&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="http://..." target="_blank">Reporting&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>

</ul>
```

The generated code(url's removed for being excessivly long.)(They are valid)
Basically, it is a series of fancy looking buttons, each of which links somewhere.  I need to calculate the link after the button is pushed, instead of before, sadly, due to processing time(the link generation method involvs joining multiple data tables, some encryption...)

Ok, after additional research, it seems that the only way to do this is to have all the link buttons direct to another page, passing the needed information.  The other page takes that information, generates the final link, and then redirects to that link.

Of course, this is somewhat cumbersome, as I am essencially taking a menu, directing to a gateway, which directs to another gateway, which might direct to another gateway, before getting there.

Comment: Can you show us some examples of what the placeholder will look like when rendered?

Comment: And... the generated html has been added.  I would show you what the menu looks like, but it does not seem to be useful info here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you want to calculate the actual link to go to when the link is clicked, before the default link behavior is executed and the page redirects away. You can do that like this:

```
$('#phAgentMenu').find('a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //this prevents the link from redirecting
    //now calculate your link
    var linkDestination = yourLinkCalculation();
    window.location.href = linkDestination;
});
```

Comment: Sadly, it is not the link calculation, it is the need to not calculate on load, but on click.

Comment: @Archmage1 I don't understand. Are you saying that you need to calculate the link before it actually redirects to the original one, and then redirect to the calculated link? You can do that, if so. I updated my answer.